# BitBucket get list of all contributors

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Is there a way using the BitBucket API to get a list of all commiters/contributors to a repository?

I know I can user **git-shortlog** for this purpose but would rather make an API call if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we do not currently have that kind of data indexed, or available through the API.

Comment: I have "solved" id by going over all commits and collecting authors ... it is not the fastest solution but it works. GitHub has a nice simple API call to solve this.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. If you're going to do that though, it'll be way faster to just clone the repo and compile it locally with something like:

$ git log --format="%ae" | sort | uniq -c

Comment: I know, but I would like to obtain some BitBucket specific info, like author id, etc. I went ahead an did this, I store the last commit id so next time I stop as soon as I find the same commit id.

Comment: FWIW, you could still perform all this locally and use the API to resolve email addresses to Bitbucket accounts by hitting: https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/evzijst@atlassian.com