# In Bitbucket API, how can I get a list of ALL licensed users?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I've looked at the [Bitbucket API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/) and this post [BitBucket get list of all contributors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472966/bitbucket-get-list-of-all-contributors). The second link asks about users belonging to a repo, but in my case I just want a list of ALL licensed users. Is there really NO way to do this or did I miss it in the docs?

Comment: Are you asking about Bitbucket Server? Both links you've provided are for Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org), which has a different API structure.

Comment: Sorry yes, Bitbucket server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Execute something like this:

```
curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/admin/users?limit=1000 | jq --raw-output '.values[] | .name + " => " + .displayName'
```

And you'll get the "username => name" list of users.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and get "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 10". I do have jq installed

Comment: Uhm... to check if it's a concatenation issue, run only this: curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/admin/users?limit=1000 | jq --raw-output '.values[] | .name'

Comment: Forgot the api version. So this works: curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/admin/users?limit=1000 | jq --raw-output '.values[] | .name'

Answer (score 4):

Just for anyone else looking for this: The currently accepted answer provides a way to list all users, but this will include *unlicensed* users, i.e. user records that are not currently consuming a seat.

If you want to get a list of all licensed users, follow the steps described in [How do I find which users count against my Bitbucket Server license?](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-do-i-find-which-users-count-against-my-bitbucket-server-license-779171685.html) to install an add-on which will give you exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some python code that did the trick for me.  I had many users (10k+) but <1000 users with permissions.  I also have basic authentication (username/passoword) enabled for my bitbucket server.  By querying both "users" and "permissions" and merging the results using pandas, I got a pretty good result.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import requests
import datetime
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

bitbucket_url = "https://my-bitbucket-server" 
users_url = bitbucket_url + "/rest/api/1.0/admin/users?limit=1000&start="
permissions_url = bitbucket_url + "/rest/api/1.0/admin/permissions/users?limit=1000&start="
out_filename = r"C:\mypath\authenticatedUsers.csv"

username = "myusername"
password = "mypassword"

def get_responses(url,username,password):
    json_responses = []
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.auth = (username,password)
        start = 0
        while(True):
            response = s.get(url + str(start),verify=False)
            json_response = json.loads(response.text)
            if "values" not in json_response:
                print("Error:" + response.text)
            json_responses += json_response["values"]
            if(len(json_response["values"]) < 1000):
                break
            start += 1000
    return json_responses

users = pd.DataFrame(get_responses(users_url,username=username,password=password))
users["DaysSinceAuth"] = np.floor((datetime.datetime.now().timestamp() - users.lastAuthenticationTimestamp/1000)/3600/24)
permissions = get_responses(permissions_url,username=username,password=password)
permissions = pd.DataFrame([{"id":p["user"]["id"],"permission":p["permission"]} for p in permissions])
usersmerged = users.merge(permissions,how="inner",on="id")
usersmerged.to_csv(out_filename)
```