# API to get list or repos owned by a Bitbucket-server user?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-server, bitbucket-api

As a follow up to [In Bitbucket API, how can I get a list of ALL licensed users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616922/in-bitbucket-api-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-licensed-users/49617617#49617617), I know want to find ALL the repos owned by a user. However, the [BB-server API](https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.9.0/bitbucket-rest.html#paging-params) doesn't seem to provide a filter for the repos endpoint? Moreover, seems like repos do not have a concept of an owner? IOW If I do

```
$ curl -s -u USER:PW -X GET https://bitbucket-server.domain.com/bitbucket/rest/api/1.0/repos?name=apr-util | jq --raw-output '.values[]'
```

I get

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "https://bitbucket-server.domain.com/bitbucket/projects/CAGLXY/repos/apr-util/browse"
      }
    ],
    "clone": [
      {
        "name": "ssh",
        "href": "ssh://git@bitbucket-server.domain.com:7999/caglxy/apr-util.git"
      },
      {
        "name": "http",
        "href": "https://user@bitbucket-server.domain.com/bitbucket/scm/caglxy/apr-util.git"
      }
    ]
  },
  "public": false,
  "slug": "apr-util",
  "id": 6289,
  "name": "apr-util",
  "scmId": "git",
  "state": "AVAILABLE",
  "statusMessage": "Available",
  "forkable": true,
  "project": {
    "links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "https://bitbucket-server.domain.com/bitbucket/projects/CAGLXY"
        }
      ]
    },
    "type": "NORMAL",
    "public": false,
    "description": "Project to house company's Ansible Git repos",
    "name": "ansible-galaxy",
    "id": 1883,
    "key": "CAGLXY"
  }
}
```

and I don't see an "owner" attribute. Is there no DIRECT way to get a list of repos owned by a user? If no, how would I go about compiling a list of repos owned by a user?

Answer (score 2):

The non-personal repositories don't have owners but you can list the personal repositories with the following command:

```
curl -s --user USER:PASS --request GET https://BITBUCKET-SERVER/rest/api/1.0/projects/~USER/repos | jq --raw-output '.values[].slug'
```

Comment: Thanks again. I did see this regarding personal repos. But I am correct that non-personal-but-not-public repos (need to log in to see) don't have owners either correct?

Comment: Yes, non-personal repositories don't have owners.